# Consuming a Cluste RabbitMq's queue using Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue

I've developed a consumer using Python and pika.

My connections with my local RabbitMq works well but when I try to use my company environment I have problems to conect.

to conect directly im my local RabbitMq I use this and works well:
1 ) `channel.queue_declare(queue='massive_queue')`

to connect with a cluster I tried my first approach with this error:
`pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (406, "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'partner-portal_new-batch-process-file' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true'")`

and these:
It is durable, and I have used : 2) `channel.queue_declare(queue='massive_queue', durable=True)`
and reveived this error:
`pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (406, "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'partner-portal_new-batch-process-file' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'classic' of type 'longstr'")`

And now I try use arguments : 3) `channel.queue_declare(queue='massive_queue', durable=True, arguments='{"x-queue-type"="classic"}')`

and I received this error:

```
File "../scripts/consumer_new_batch.py", line 16, in <module>
    channel.queue_declare(queue='massive_queue', durable=True, arguments='{"x-queue-type"="classic"}')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2497, in queue_declare
    self._impl.queue_declare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 825, in queue_declare
    return self._rpc(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 1348, in _rpc
    self._send_method(method)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 1405, in _send_method
    self.connection._send_method(self.channel_number, method, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/connection.py", line 2234, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Method(channel_number, method))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/connection.py", line 2219, in _send_frame
    marshaled_frame = frame_value.marshal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/frame.py", line 73, in marshal
    pieces = self.method.encode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/spec.py", line 1019, in encode
    data.encode_table(pieces, self.arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/data.py", line 90, in encode_table
    for (key, value) in table.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

[Como está no RabbitMq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvHAv.png)

Comment: I changed the arguments and it works.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to pass the parameters is:

```py
channel.queue_declare(queue='massive_queue', durable=True, arguments={"x-queue-type": "classic"})
```

`PRECONDITION_FAILED` error means that you are trying to create a queue with different parameters.

You can't change the queue parameters, you need to delete the queue and recreate it.